# Angular1.5 - truncate output data string

Tags: angularjs

The **suffix** field is to allow max 3 characters input which was already working well with the help of maxlength="3". But when it's to display component's data it's displaying unlimited even more than 3 chars) as the component sends. But we don't want to display more than 3 characters, so used **limitTo: 3** on the ng-model and the output limited to 3 characters display but the edit operation is disabled. I even tried **character:3** but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">Suffix</label>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
         <input name="suffix" type="text" gw-allow-only="numbers characters" maxlength="3" ng-disabled="borrower.miDelegatedService.editSections.borrowerinfo" ng-model="borrower.primaryBorrower.suffix | limitTo:3"
                                        class="form-control" title="{{borrower.miDelegatedService.editSections.borrowerinfo ? borrower.primaryBorrower.suffix : ''}}">
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't use any type of filter in the `ng-model` directive. Why not substring it in your controller?

Comment: ng-model is for two way binding. you can use `ng-bind` with the filter limitTo.

Comment: Thank you Lex and  Varit. I got it resolved using slice() method in the controller and it works.